# What is the mean of *X* number of patients seen?

Tags: probability, statistics, means

The source of the question below is Edgenuity's Statistics course.

> A medical device company knows that the percentage of patients experiencing injection-site reactions with the current needle is 11%. What is the mean of *X* number of patients seen until an injection-site reaction occurs?

> **A.** 3.1289
>
> **B.** 8.5763
>
> **C.** 9.0909
>
> **D.** 11

Firstly, I would like *help* in finding the correct answer, not the answer itself. Secondly, the answer appeared to be a no-brainer to me because I am not given the sample size that would be included in the equation $μ = n \cdot p$. I simply converted 11% into the decimal $0.11,$ which, yes, is the proportion, not necessarily the mean. Unless $11$ is the correct answer, I do not know where my errors are. Could you guide me on the beginning steps to the correct answer?

Comment: Have you learned about the geometric distribution?

Comment: @MatthewPilling Briefly. I know that a geometric distribution is the number of failures before the first success. Is there an equation you're implying from geometric distributions?

Comment: Think of a "success" as an injection site reaction occuring. Do you know how to find the mean of a geometric random variable?

Comment: Have you learned the mean of a geometric distribution yet? If not, the solution will require algebra and some calculus (or some familiarity with infinite sums).

Comment: @Clarinetist Yes. The equation I found in my lesson for geometric mean seems simpler than your methods: $μX = E(X) = 1/p$. Using this, the correct answer would be approx. 9.0909. I am not sure if you're "allowed" to verify if this is correct, however, did you find a different answer?

Comment: I made some edits to my answer. Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula $\mu = np$ only applies if the values of $X$ are observed as a result of a binomial experiment (or to be precise, $X$ is a binomial random variable). For a binomial experiment, **all** of the following conditions must be satisfied:

- There is a finite, pre-determined ("fixed") number of trials $n$.
- For each of the $n$ trials, there are two states: "success" and "failure," for which the probability of success is a constant $p$ for each trial.
- Each trial is independent.

The first condition above does not hold, so $\mu = np$ cannot be used.

Instead, $X$ follows a geometric distribution (though, note, [there are two types of geometric distributions in practice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution)). I assume you've probably been provided the formula for its mean and can input the appropriate probability.

To elaborate, in the case where $X$ is the number of failures **including** the first success, the mean is given by
$$E(X) = \dfrac{1}{p}\text{.}$$
If $X$ is the number of trials (that is, the number of failures **excluding** when the success occurs), the mean is given by
$$E(X) = \dfrac{1}{p} - 1 = \dfrac{1}{p} - \dfrac{p}{p} = \dfrac{1-p}{p}\text{.}$$
In this case, our "success" is when the injection-site reaction occurs.

As it stands, the question is ambiguous. The way I interpret the question is that the correct answer should be
$$E(X) = \dfrac{1-0.11}{0.11} \approx 8.0909$$
because we are interested in the number of patients seen **before** an injection-site reaction occurs. However, if we include the patients seen before the injection-site reaction occurs **and** the patient for which the injection-site reaction occurs, the answer would be
$$E(X) = \dfrac{1}{0.11} \approx 9.0909$$
yielding answer (C).

If this is the correct answer, the question should really be reworded to say something like "What is the mean of X number of patients seen **until and including** when an injection-site reaction occurs?"